# Adding numbers derived from another class?

Tags: java, inheritance

Trying to figure out how to add anumber derived from one class in another class,

```
public class ThreeNumScorer extends ThreeNum {
    // FIELDS
    public ThreeNumScorer(int no1, int no2, int no3) {
        super(no1, no2, no3);
    }
    //CONSTRUCTORS
    ThreeNum newThreeNum = new ThreeNum(no1, no2, no3);

    // METHODS
    public int getSamePoint() {
        return (newThreeNum.threeSame() + 60);
    }
}
```

So basically the user will enter 3 numbers between 1- 6 in a seperate program the first program (ThreeNum) will organise the numbers depeneding if they are consecutive numbers, all the same or different.

The above program is supposed to add points to the result of the input
i.e if user inputs 3,3,3 the result should be 69 ( 3+3+3 =9 +60 = 69)

Comment: And what exactly is your specific Problem? BTW: You have your fields defined unter `//CUSTRUCTORS` and your constructor defined under `//FIELDS`

Comment: What is your question? Describe your problem, i.e. where you are stuck and provide more code.

Comment: I wonder why are there so many "questions" without question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to have `ThreeNum newThreeNum = new ThreeNum(no1, no2, no3);`
 I don't know what you named your variables in the parent class, but if they are `no1`, `no2`, and `no3`, this should work for your summation method.

```
public int getSamePoint() {
    return (no1 + no2 + no2 + 60);
}
```